# Python - how do I call external python programs?

Tags: python, call, external

***I'll preface this by saying it's a homework assignment. I don't want code written out for me, just to be pointed in the right direction.***

We're able to work on a project of our choice so I'm working on a program to be a mini portfolio of everything I've written so far. So I'm going to make a program that the user will input the name of a program (chosen from a given list) and then run the chosen program within the existing shell.

However, I can't really find information on how to call upon external programs. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I considered putting all the code in one long program with a bunch of if loops to execute the right code, but I'd like to make it a BIT more complicated than that.

Comment: Posting on a programming site and asking not to get code is like going to a water park and asking not to get wet.

Comment: I'm more asking for the concept. I like the satisfaction of teaching myself.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you want to call each as a Python script, you can do

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["python", "myscript.py"])
subprocess.call(["python", "myscript2.py"])
```

But a better way is to call functions you've written in other scripts, like this:

```
import myscript
import myscript2

myscript.function_from_script1()
myscript2.function_from_script2()
```

Where `function_from_script1()` etc are defined in the myscript.py and myscript2.py files. See this page on [modules](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html) for more information.

Answer (score 5):

Check out the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) documentation.

Answer (score 4):

Also if you need to pass additional arguments do this:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["python", "myscript.py", "arg1", "arg2", "argN"])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load an external Python file and run it inside the current interpreter without the burden to dealing with modules, you can use the standard [importlib.util](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib.util) module.

This is useful when you need to ship some Python scripts for demonstration purposes, but you don't want to make them part of a (sub-)module--while still being able to run them automatically, like during integration testing. Here is an example:

```
# A sample Python script
sh$ cat snippet/demo.py 
SOME_MODULE_GLOBAL=True
print("Hello, here is the demo snippet!")
# There is no `__init__.py in the _snippet_ directory
sh$ cat snippet/__init__.py
cat: snippet/__init__.py: No such file or directory
```

Now using `importlib.util` you can load `demo.py` even if it is not part of a module:

```
>>> import importlib.util

# Bypass the standard import machinery to manually load a Python script from
# a filepath
>>> spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location('demo','snippet/demo.py')
>>> spec
ModuleSpec(name='demo', loader=<_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fa549344eb8>, origin='snippet/demo.py')
>>> module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
>>> module
<module 'demo' from 'snippet/demo.py'>

# The next command will run the module:
>>> spec.loader.exec_module(module)
Hello, here is the demo snippet!

# Module variables are accessible just like if it was a
# _normally_ imported module:
>>> module.SOME_MODULE_GLOBAL
True
```