# Python: calling another python script

Tags: python, import, subprocess

Is it possible to call another python script to access just the definitions inside the script and nothing else?

In the script I want to import, there are plots that I want to suppress since there an not needed for this other program.  That is, I only want to access the definitions of the Stumpff functions without plotting the figures.

The script I want to import is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ipython
#  This program plots the Stumpff functions C(z) and S(z)

import numpy as np
import pylab
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator


def C(z):
    if z > 0:
        return (1 - np.cos(z ** 0.5)) / z
    elif z < 0:
        return (np.cosh(np.sqrt(-z)) - 1) / -z
    return 0.5


def S(z):
    if z > 0:
        return (np.sqrt(z) - np.sin(z ** 0.5)) / np.sqrt(z) ** 3
    elif z < 0:
        return (np.sinh(np.sqrt(-z)) - np.sqrt(-z)) / np.sqrt(-z) ** 3
    return 1.0 / 6.0


vC = np.vectorize(C)
vS = np.vectorize(S)

z = np.linspace(-50.0, 500.0, 100000.0)
y = vC(z)
y2 = vS(z)

fig = pylab.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(z, y, 'r')
ax.plot(z, y2, 'b')
pylab.legend(('$C(z)$', '$S(z)$'), loc = 0)
pylab.xlim((-50, 0))
pylab.ylim((0, 12))
pylab.xlabel('$z$')
pylab.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(prune = 'lower'))
pylab.savefig('stumpffneg50to0.eps', format = 'eps')


fig2 = pylab.figure()
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(111)
ax2.plot(z, y, 'r')
ax2.plot(z, y2, 'b')
pylab.legend(('$C(z)$', '$S(z)$'), loc = 1)
pylab.xlim((0, 30))
pylab.ylim((0, 0.5))
pylab.xlabel('$z$')
pylab.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(prune = 'lower'))
pylab.savefig('stumpff0to30.eps', format = 'eps')


fig3 = pylab.figure()
ax3 = fig3.add_subplot(111)
ax3.plot(z, y, 'r')
ax3.plot(z, y2, 'b')
pylab.legend(('$C(z)$', '$S(z)$'), loc = 0)
pylab.xlim((0, 500))
pylab.ylim((0, 0.05))
pylab.xlabel('$z$')
pylab.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(prune = 'lower'))
pylab.savefig('stumpff0to500.eps', format = 'eps')
pylab.show()
```

From reading [python how do I call external python programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318581/python-how-do-i-call-external-python-programs), I see that I have add

```
import stumpff
```

After that, will my new script understand `C(z)` and `S(z)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way your script is written, there is no way to import it and not have the plots made.

To make it so that `import stumpff` will work, and your script will understand C(z) and S(z), you'll need to make the plotting code such that it will only run if you are running as a script. One way to do this is to put all of it in a main() function, and then use

```python
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Alternatively, simply have all of it underneath that condition, like this:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env ipython
#  This program plots the Stumpff functions C(z) and S(z)

import numpy as np
import pylab
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator


def C(z):
    if z > 0:
        return (1 - np.cos(z ** 0.5)) / z
    elif z < 0:
        return (np.cosh(np.sqrt(-z)) - 1) / -z
    return 0.5


def S(z):
    if z > 0:
        return (np.sqrt(z) - np.sin(z ** 0.5)) / np.sqrt(z) ** 3
    elif z < 0:
        return (np.sinh(np.sqrt(-z)) - np.sqrt(-z)) / np.sqrt(-z) ** 3
    return 1.0 / 6.0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    vC = np.vectorize(C)
    vS = np.vectorize(S)

    z = np.linspace(-50.0, 500.0, 100000.0)
    y = vC(z)
    y2 = vS(z)

    fig = pylab.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.plot(z, y, 'r')
    ax.plot(z, y2, 'b')
    pylab.legend(('$C(z)$', '$S(z)$'), loc = 0)
    pylab.xlim((-50, 0))
    pylab.ylim((0, 12))
    pylab.xlabel('$z$')
    pylab.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(prune = 'lower'))
    pylab.savefig('stumpffneg50to0.eps', format = 'eps')


    fig2 = pylab.figure()
    ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(111)
    ax2.plot(z, y, 'r')
    ax2.plot(z, y2, 'b')
    pylab.legend(('$C(z)$', '$S(z)$'), loc = 1)
    pylab.xlim((0, 30))
    pylab.ylim((0, 0.5))
    pylab.xlabel('$z$')
    pylab.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(prune = 'lower'))
    pylab.savefig('stumpff0to30.eps', format = 'eps')


    fig3 = pylab.figure()
    ax3 = fig3.add_subplot(111)
    ax3.plot(z, y, 'r')
    ax3.plot(z, y2, 'b')
    pylab.legend(('$C(z)$', '$S(z)$'), loc = 0)
    pylab.xlim((0, 500))
    pylab.ylim((0, 0.05))
    pylab.xlabel('$z$')
    pylab.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(prune = 'lower'))
    pylab.savefig('stumpff0to500.eps', format = 'eps')
    pylab.show()
```

Then, you can use `import stumpff`, and you can use `stumpff.C(z)` and `stumpff.S(z)`. If you want to be able to use them without `stumpff` before them, then use `from stumpff import *`, or `from stumpff import C, S`

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try and then work it as accepted if it works.